What is Guru droha? Is there any atonement for it in scriptures?
What is Guru droha?
Some say it can be only atoned by self immolation..Like Kumarila Bhatta ji.
Is there any prayaschitta for guru droha in shastras?

Guru droha could be doing something severely displeasing to the Guru. Asking forgiveness from the Guru himself is the prayaschitta.

Kindly quote references..thanks

Should burn oneself in fire.

see answer for padma-purāṇa reference.

I) In order to ascertain Gurudroka astrologically through Janma Patrikā(जन्म पत्रिका/Horoscope/ஜாதகம்), primarily look for Guru-Cāṇḍāla yoga (गुरु-चाण्डाल योग) which is formed when “Jupiter conjoins Rahu” or “Jupiter and Rahu aspect each other”. This yoga should further be afflicted at the hands of Mars or Saturn either through conjunction or aspect. Moreover, the 9th house (House of Dharma, Religion and Preceptor) and its lord should be also scrutinized for affliction. Along with Guru-Cāṇḍāla yoga marred with affliction, if 9th house and its lord are also afflicted, then possibility of occurrence of Gurudroka is to be predicted. This should be further corroborated with a similar analysis on Navāmsa (D9) chart. Beware-1: Jupiter's Graha Devatha is Brihaspati(Guru) and Rahu is being considered as Cāṇḍāla, therefore, this combination pollutes Jupiter and so, goes by the name Guru-Cāṇḍāla yoga. Beware-2: To know about each planet's Graha Devatha, Adhi Devatha and Pratyadi Devatha, please refer How does the janam kundli of 9 grahas, Surya graha, chandra graha, etc. look like? Beware-3: According to Bhāvāth Bhāva(भावात् भाव), 9th to 9th is the 5th house, so 5th house and its lord should also be scrutinized identical to 9th house and 9th lord in order to ascertain their affliction.
II) Chāndogya Upanishad(छान्दोग्योपनिषद्) [5.10.9] says about 4 pāthakās including violating teacher’s bed:

स्तेनो हिरण्यस्य सुरां पिबंश्च गुरोस्तल्पमावसन्ब्रह्महा ।
चैते पतन्ति चत्वारः पञ्चमश्चाचरंस्तैरिति ॥ ५.१०.९ ॥

steno hiraṇyasya surāṃ pibaṃśca gurostalpamāvasanbrahmahā ।
caite patanti catvāraḥ pañcamaścācaraṃstairiti || 5.10.9 ||

A person who steals gold, or drinks liquor, or goes to bed with
his teacher’s wife or kills a brāhmin—these four are lost.  
Also lost is the fifth—one who keeps company with such people.

— Chāndogya Upanishad: Verse 5.10.9


Thus Chāndogya Upanishad considers “Going to bed with teacher’s wife" as a pāthaka(पातक) resulting in person’s fall. Refer the penultimate point (VI) to know punishment for such a crime as said by Viṣhṇu Purāṇa. However, Vishnu Smriti(विष्णुस्मृति) offers Prāyaścitta(प्रायश्चित्त/Atonement),  refer the discussion at point (V) below.
III) Atri Smriti(अत्रिस्मृति) [sloka-10] says the disciple will be punished severely for disrespecting Guru who taught him even a single syllable.

एकाक्षरप्रदातारं यो गुरुं नाभिवन्दते ।
श्वानयोनिशतं गत्वा चाण्डालेष्वभिजायते ॥ १० ॥

ekākṣara-pradātāraṁ yo guruṁ nābhivandate |
śvāna-yoni-śataṁ gatvā cāṇḍāleṣv abhijāyate || 10 ||

One who does not respect a guru, who has taught [even] a single syllable, 
will undergo one hundred births as a dog and then be born among cāṇḍālas. 

— Atri Smriti: sloka-10


The offender will be punished 100 punarjanmas in continuity as a dog and finally will be born as a cāṇḍāla.
IV) Manu Smriti(मनुस्मृति) [12.58] says violator of a Guru’s bed will be punished severely.

तृणगुल्मलतानां च क्रव्यादां दंष्ट्रिणामपि ।
क्रूरकर्मकृतां चैव शतशो गुरुतल्पगः ॥ १२.५८॥

tṛṇagulmalatānāṃ ca kravyādāṃ daṃṣṭriṇāmapi |
krūrakarmakṛtāṃ caiva śataśo gurutalpagaḥ || 12.58 ||

The violator of a Guru’s bed [enters] a hundred times [the forms] of grasses,
shrubs, and creepers,likewise of carnivorous [animals] and of [beasts] 
with fangs and of those doing cruel deeds. 

— Manu Smriti: Ch-12 sloka-58


Manu Smriti asserts that violators should undergo punarjanma 100 times assuming the embodiment of grasses, shrubs, creepers, animals and other beasts in continuity as punishment!
V) Vishnu Smriti(विष्णुस्मृति) [12.58; PageNo: 110/244] says violating a Guru’s bed will be considered as Mahāpādakam (very serious offence) and suggests Prāyaścitta(प्रायश्चित्त/Atonement/Expiation) for those crimes.

ब्रह्महत्या सुरापानम् ब्राह्मणसुवर्णहरणां गुरुदारगमनमिति महापातकानि॥ ३५.१ ॥

brahmahatya surāpānam brāhmanasvarnaharanām gurudāragamanamiti mahāpātakani ||35.1||

Killing a Brâhmana, drinking spirituous liquor, 
stealing the gold of a Brâhmana, and
sexual connection with a Guru's wife are high crimes.

अश्वमेधेन शुद्धेयुर्महापातकिनस्त्विमे ।
पृथिव्यां सर्वतीर्थानां तथानुसरणवे च ॥ ३५.६॥

ashvamedhena  suddeyurmahāpātakinastvame |
prutivyām sarvatīrthanām tathānusaranave ca ||35.6|| 

Such mortal sinners are purified by a horse sacrifice [ashvamedha yajña] and 
by visiting all Tîrthas [tīrtha yātra/places of pilgrimage].

— Vishnu Smriti: Ch-35 sloka-1 and sloka-6


Beware-4: Vishnu Smriti offers Prāyaścitta(प्रायश्चित्त/Atonement) for this heinous crime.
VI) Viṣhṇu Purāṇa [Book-2, Chapter-6, Sloka-10] talks about the punishment for those who violated Guru's bed.

राजन्यवैश्यहा ताले तथैव गुरुतल्पगः ।
तप्तगुण्डे स्वसृगामी हन्ति राजभटांश्च य​: ॥ ६.१०॥

rājanyavaisyaha tāle tathaiva gurutalpagah |
taptagunde svasrugāmī hanti rājabhadāshca yah ||6.10||

The murderer of a man of the second or third varna, and
one who is guilty of adultery with the wife of his spiritual teacher,
is sentenced to the Tāla [ताल/padlock] hell. 

— Vishnu Purana: Book-2, Ch-6, Sloka-10


Thus, according to Viṣhṇu Purāṇa, the violator of Guru's bed will be punished in Tāla(ताल​) hell.
Update: Since OP has commented for asking about a practical instance of Gurudroka with scriptural references, this new point (VII) has been added up. This story has been mentioned in Devi Bhāgavata Purana, Brahma Vaivarta Purana, Vishnu Purana, Shiva Purana, Brahmānda Purana, Harivansha Purana, Bhāgavata Purana and Padma Purana.
VII) Devi Bhāgavata Purāṇa [Book-1, Chapter-11, Sloka: 1-86] talks about the story of Soma (aka Chandra, son of Maharishi Atri and Anasūya) who abducted his preceptor Brihaspati's wife Tārā resulted in great chaos. This is an instance of direct gurudroka actually committed according to Devi Bhāgavata Purāṇa.
Having his wife been abducted by Soma, Brihaspati sent over and over again his disciples and when Soma returned the messengers empty handed, Brihaspati became very angry and went personally to Soma's house and spoke angrily to the Moon who was puffed up with arrogance and smirk:

O Soma! Why are you committing this vicious act, contrary to Dharma?
Why are you keeping my beautiful wife in your house? I am your Guru;
you are my Sisya [disciple]; O stupid! why are you enjoying your Guru’s wife
and keeping her in custody in your house? Do you not know that he who
kills a Brāhman, who steals gold, who drinks, who goes to wife of
one’s Guru are Mahāpātakis [great sinners] and those who keep company
of these are the fifth Mahāpātakis? Therefore if you had enjoyed my
wife, you are exceedingly vicious, blameable and a Mahāpātaki [great sinner];
you are not fit to live amongst the Devas. O wicked one! Now
I say that even now you better forsake Tārā, who is of a blue colour
and whose look is askance; I won’t go from here without having Tārā.
And if you do not give back Tārā, then you are certainly with her and
undoubtedly I will curse you.

— Devi Bhāgavata Purāṇa: 1.11.1-86


Despite Devaguru Brihaspati spoke about panca Mahāpātakas as mentioned in Chāndogya Upanishad [refer point (II) discussed above] which considers “Going to bed with teacher’s wife" as a pāthaka(पातक) resulting in person’s fall, the adamant Soma finally replied:

O Guru! I will not give you back your wife; do what you wish.

Subsequently a great war (infamously known as Tārakāmayam) ensued wherein Devas (under Indra) fought against Soma (Asura Guru Śukrācārya and Dānavas who sided him) and it continued for many years. Finally Brahama appeared and upon his advice Soma returned to Brihaspati his wife Tārā.
Conclusion:
From the foregone discussion, it is evident that only Vishnu Smriti(विष्णुस्मृति) [12.58] offers Prāyaścitta(प्रायश्चित्त/Atonement/Expiation) for guru droha:

Such mortal sinners are purified by a horse sacrifice [ashvamedha
yajña] and  by visiting all Tîrthas [Tīrtha Yātra/Places of pilgrimage].

— Vishnu Smriti: 12.58


Good Luck!

This is an indirect answer sir..do you know any shloka that mentions guru droha directly?

@Harsh The story of Soma (aka Chandra, son of Maharishi Athri and Anasūya) who abducted his preceptor Brahaspathi's wife Tārā resulted in great chaos. This is an example of direct guru droka narrated in Shiva Purana. Let me update the story directly in the conclusion of this post. Do you expect something else?

@Harsh , it is done. Good Luck!

I am a Dwaitin sir

Fantastic! Nowadays, it is hard to meet a dvaida follower. Now I know why you avoided Shiva Purana! Never mind. Thanks for the reply. Good Luck!

Welcome Sir..thanks for the wishes

I heard from Saints all tirthas are present in Radha and shyam kund and bathing in them gives the result of ashwamedh and rajsuya resp.

@ShriHarivansh , Sri Rama, Nahusa and others performed ashvamedha
yajña. Dharma Putra in Mahabharatam observed Rajasuya yajña. They could have taken a dip in those theertha and could have obtained the phala (result) efforlessly! Why did they not do dipping? Why did they opt for harder way? Even dipping in Ganges alone absolves all sorts of sin!

@Marmayogi then lord says in bg that I am japa yagya then why people still think ashwamedh better than naam japa?? All kinds of people exist if you with faith take a dip I take yours guarantee that you will definately attain krishna (according to 6 goswamis) and Shri Radha (kund is topmost teerth according to many vaishnavas and everyone knows glory of Govardhan is impossible to be countered by any teertha..Radha kund was made in dwapar not treta so it was not possible for Shri Ram to take a dip and lord himself says my bhakta is superior to karma kandis

@Marmayogi in braj there was Pandavas tree and when it going to be cut for shyam kund yudhishthir ji requested to Radha kund vaishnav(raghunath das) to not cut as they were doing sadhana there(they know its glory) if you compare ashwamedh with Radha kund it is simple foolishness(ask any vaishnava) and you might know shiv parvati prasang where parvati  ji say they all will destroy their sins I know devi Ganga's glory and lord Shiva told how only the one who had trust could actually destroy his sins other people's ganga snan was not even considered ganga snana according to lord shiva

It is fact,  whether ashvamedha yajña,  Rajasuya yajña, or dipping in theerthas, all should be conducted with commitment.   OP’s question was Is there any prayaschitta for guru droha in shastras? If at all I have to answer, then scriptural evidence for Gurudroha Prayachitam must be supplied. This was provided by Vishnu Smriti. That is all. If any sastras says dipping in Radha kund wipes out Gurudroha, I will be glad to put it down in the post. @ShriHarivansh , please understand that without scriptural evidence no answer will be accepted. However, I respect your comments. Thanks.

@Marmayogi since you said that visiting all teerth and ashwamedh was the solution therefore I recommended Radha kund because in Varaha Purana it's phal is said to be equal to ashwamedh and in the same purana the total number of teerthas were mentioned (i forgot thousands of crores)which is impossible to visit by anyone in his complete life. Yet best pryaschitta is to ask for forgiveness from guru

@Marmayogi it's pryaschitta according to Vishnu smrit and varaha Purana will be visiting mathura(for visiting all tirthas which are sixty thousand and sixty hundred crores in number 159.5 Varaha Purana) and a dip in Radha kund, I also respect your comments thanks.

@ShriHarivansh  it is not just Kund but  pilgrimage. If it is only Kund then each state in India has hundreds of sacred ponds, and it is humanly impossible to visit all! What Vishnu Smriti suggests is pilgrimage places such as  Rameshwarm, Narmada, Kasi, Gaya, and Badrinath. Probably ten to twenty important places. You are right, best prayaschitta is to ask for forgiveness from guru, however it is not mentioned in Vishnu Smriti. Please have a look at the comments present at the Post and this was already suggested! But OP was asking for Scriptural support. Thanks.

@Harsh fyi, Yajnavalkya Samhita [3.260] says that a violator of a preceptor's bed must perform the most distressing penance of Prajapatya for a year; or he should study the Veda-Samhita and perform the Chandrayana for three months.

tldr: direct reference in padma-purāṇa mentioned in the bottom of the answer.
Gurudroha is variously translated as "violence to the teacher" or "deceiving the teacher (or elders)". It is mentioned in a lot of scriptures. I will list some direct mentions. I am sure someone else can help with the translation.
Gurudroha is divided four-fold in the Gurukramādhikārasūtra of the Manthanabhairavatantra:

caturvidhaṃ gurudrohaṃ sarveṣāṃ patanaṃ bhavet || 
āśramadarśanānāṃ ca viśeṣeṇa tu paścime | 
gurorājñā gurordravyaṃ gurukāryaṃ gurustriyam || 
uttarottaro vai śiṣye gurodrohaś caturvidhaḥ |
vidveṣabaddhabandhāni mahāsāhasikādikam ||
evaṃ muktvā gurudrohaṃ nānyaiḥ pāpais tu lipyate | Yogakhaṇḍa (1) 22/25cd-33ab.


There are four types of violence to which the teacher may be subject (gurudroha) that brings about the fall of all (and anybody who does it to him) but especially those who have (pledged to follow the teachings of the) Hermitage in the Western (tradition). In increasing order (of gravity) the fourfold sin of violence to the teacher (found) in the disciple is (violence to) the teacher's Command, the teacher’s substance, the teacher’s task and the teacher’s woman. Great acts of disrespect and the like are bound with the bonds of aversion. Freed from such violence to the teacher (gurudroha), one is not stained by other sins.

The Kāmikāgama Uttarabhāga chapter 30 seems to equal Gurudroha with Śivadroha:

akāmataḥ prakāśe ca tatrāpyayutakadvayam | 
gurudrohādṛte śuddhiḥ kāmato'pi bhavediha || 655 || 
tadyādvā deśikastasya tadākṛcchra purassaram | 
punaryāgaḥ prakartavyasśuddhistasyānyathāna hi || 656 || 
pātakatraya saṃyogassāmānyo brāhmaṇāditaḥ | 
madyapānaṃ yadā śūdre'dīkṣite svalpakaṃ bhavet || 657 || 
niṣedhābhāvatastasya doṣastatra na jāyate | 
niyamādghora jāpasya prakartavyaṃ śataṃ trikam || 658 || 
gurustrīgamanaṃ yaccha caturṇāṃ sadṛśaṃ bhavet | 
gurudrohaḥ śivadrohastasmāttat pātakaṃ bhavet || 659 || 
kāṣṭhādi pārthivasteye tejodravyaṃ vinā drijāḥ | 
sadyojātajapācchuddhirakāmādiha kathyate || 660 ||

The Kubjikamatatantra chapter 5 semes to mention purification rites associated with Gurudroha.

sāmprataṃ śṛṇu kalyāṇi vidyāmāhātmyamuttamam |
sevanājjapahomādvā dhyānācca kramaśo bhavet || 42 ||
ṣaṇmāsāccotpateddevi sat yametadudāhṛtam |
kṛtvā sāmrāṭajāndoṣānuccārātkalmaṣāpaham || 43 ||
devadrohe gurudrohe koṭitriṃśaiḥ sa śudhyati |
chedane puṣpapattrāṇāmāvartācchudhyate tu saḥ || 44 || 

Gurudroha is also mentioned in a variety of Purāṇas. The Skanda Purāṇa chapter 3.2.27 for instance makes mention of the act including the manner of purification:

50-53. By glorifying it, one gets more merits. By resorting to it becomes extremely conducive to salvation. Sinners of various sorts such as a Brāhmaṇa-slayer, mother-slayer, killer of children, cow-slayer, murderer of women and Śūdras, one who gives poison, one guilty of arson, those who are bent on tormenting elders (gurudroha-rata), those who censure ascetics, those who commit perjury, one who magnifies the defects of others in his speech and one who wilfully conceals good qualities of others, in fact, one who is guilty of all these sinful deeds, become released (from the sins) by visiting the Liṅga.

Similarly, the Padma-Purāṇa chapter 6.34 also mentions the act including the manner of purification of the resulting sin thereof:

Prācī Mādhava said: 28-35. I shall undoubtedly tell you. O daughter, do not weep. My place is the Śyāma Vaṭa; and Prācī Devī, daughter of Brahmā, flows in front of me. Looking at the chief goddess, every day bathe there. By that you will be purified. There is no doubt that I stay along with hundreds of holy places and gods there where there is Prācī, Brahmā’s daughter. My place is pure and dear (to me). It destroys (the sin of) crores of murders. Since you are dearer to me than my (own) life, I, being pleased, have given it to you. O Jāhnavī, by my order thousands of crores of holy places always remain in the water of Prācī Sarasvatī. O daughter, Brahmā’s daughter Prācī removes all sins on bathing once (only) in front of me (in her water). (She removes) sins due to the murder of a brāhmaṇa, drinking liquor, killing a cow or a śūdra woman, snatching the wealth of a brāhmaṇa, not honouring one’s mother and father, using a vehicle, deceiving one’s preceptor (gurudroha), or eating what is prohibited. O best river, bathe (there). You will be free from sins.

The variant Gurudrohī is found equally often. You can find more references here.
